# Syntax Error: Encountered "RECURRING"

Tags: java, sql, database, syntax-error, javadb

I was trying to write a SQL statement that updates my database with the new information given. When I run the program it gives me an error saying that it has encountered "RECURRING" at line 1, column 401. What does this mean? I've added to the database using this word before, so I don't understand what the issue is. Here's the code...

```
stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE \"CUSTOMERS\" SET FIRSTNAME = " + "'" + customer.getFirstName() + "'" + ", LASTNAME = " + "'" + customer.getLastName() + "'" + ", EMAIL = " + "'" + customer.getEmail() + "'" + ", PHONE = " + "'" + customer.getPhone() + "'" + ", ADDRESS = " + "'" + customer.getAddress() + "'" + ", GROUPONNUMBER = " + "'" + customer.getGrouponNumber() + "'" + ", NOTES = " + "'" + customer.getNotes() + "'" + ", ONETIME = " + customer.getOneTime() + ", RECURRING = " + customer.getRecurring()+ ", NONRESPONSIVE = " + customer.getNonResponsive() + " WHERE FIRSTNAME = " + "'" + active.getFirstName() + "'" + " AND LASTNAME = " + "'" + active.getLastName() + "'" + " AND EMAIL = " + "'" + active.getEmail() + "'" + "AND PHONE = " + "'" + active.getPhone() + "'" + "AND ADDRESS = " + "'" + active.getAddress() + "'" + "AND GROUPONNUMBER =  " + "'" + active.getGrouponNumber() + "'" + "AND NOTES = " + "'" + active.getNotes() + "'" + " AND ONETIME = " + active.getOneTime() + "AND RECURRING = " + active.getRecurring() + "AND GROUPON = " + active.getGroupon() + "AND NONRESPONSIVE = " + active.getNonResponsive());
```

I've haven't used SQL too much, so I don't really know what I'm doing to be honest.

Comment: You're missing spaces after some of your double quotes (near the "recurring" column. Something tells me this isn't the best way to do this in Java as well. I'm not a Java developer, but typically building a SQL string to then run is bad for many reasons (not the least of which is that it's very prone to bugs like this one.)

Comment: this is the 1,000,000th java tag - http://imgur.com/xx2MzGj

Comment: Haha oh wow. That's pretty cool @iliketocode

Comment: Which spaces are you talking about? Yeah it probably isn't, but I don't know any other way to do it. @TomH Hey I just fixed the spaces, and now I'm getting a error talking about a comparison between LONG VARCHAR and CHAR

Comment: You are building your string with code like, `" AND ONETIME = " + active.getOneTime() + "AND RECURRING = "`...  Notice the lack of a space between the double quote and the word "AND"? Also, if you know that there's probably a better way, then perhaps you should Google how to write Java code against SQL and write decent code instead of writing code that you know is bad.

Comment: Thanks, I saw them now. Well I had actually learned to do it that way from a tutorial about using JavaDB @TomH

Comment: If that correctly fixed the problem then please let me know so that I can mark the question closed as a simple syntax error. Thanks

Comment: Well it did fix the error I was asking about. I ended up getting another error, but I'll work on that on my own. @TomH